# How to implement WordPress Blog in a React js App?

Tags: php, wordpress, reactjs

I have a working react app that running on Apache virtual host mydomain.com via ProxyPass.

Here is my VirtualHost configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3005/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3005/

  # This is needed only if you want to use web sockets
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
  RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I want to add a Wordpress blog in a subfolder `mydomain.com/blog`

How can we do that:

- run react app in root and
- wordpress in subfolder?

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly you tried?

Comment: node-php, express-php, php-express, php-fpm

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Listing a bunch of frameworks is not "showing us what you tried". Rather put up a specific minimal example with *code*.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [GatsbyJS](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/). It's goal is to use modern React frontend while WordPress serves as a back-office/API.